# Azure Function lifetime - static or transient per function invocation

Tags: azure-functions

Waht is the lifetime for a class that contains multiple Azure Functions (for RESTcentric functions), for example:

```
public class AttestationFunctions
{
    private readonly AttestationsTableClientFactory tableClientFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<AttestationFunctions> logger;

    public AttestationFunctions(AttestationsTableClientFactory tableClientFactory, ILogger<AttestationFunctions> log)
    {
        this.tableClientFactory = tableClientFactory;
        logger = log;
    }

    [FunctionName("List")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "attest")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        var table = this.tableClientFactory.New();
        /* snipped */
    }

    [FunctionName("Approve")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Approve([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "attest/{id}")] HttpRequest req, string id)
    {
         var table = this.tableClientFactory.New();
        /* snipped */
    }

    [FunctionName("Reject")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Reject(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete", Route = "attest/{id}")] HttpRequest req, string id)
    {
         var table = this.tableClientFactory.New();
        /* snipped */
    }
}
```

Having the table factory injected into the constructor and created on instantiation would be cleaner than creating on each function call - but this is only possible if each call is transient.

Checking the `AttestationFunctions` class is not somehow made static (which would cause issues with certain classes expecting transient/scoped expectations).

Is there a bootstrap setting that would change this (so can code defensively incase an expected lifetime setting was overruled)?

My second question is that the factory is actually an async method, which should be called per function call (so it can be cancelled, not in the constructor) - would one want to cache a table instance or pool them or one per function call?

```
public class AttestationsTableClientFactory
{
    private readonly IAttestationSettings settings;

    public AttestationsTableClientFactory(IAttestationSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public async Task<TableClient> New(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var tableClient = new TableClient(settings.AttestationsTableConnectionString, "Attestations");
        await tableClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(cancellationToken);
        return tableClient;
    }
}
```

Appreciate confirmation on this, my google/SO/MSDN searches have been lacking in this regard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is instantiated when the functions are first loaded and is so as long as the functions instance is running. Note that this is per instance of function app running, so as your app scales up or down, this class is instantiated or disposed for each instance.

As for how the client should be used, the recommendation is to re-use clients to [manage connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp) due to limits imposed to function apps.

If you have multiple classes, you should use [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp) to further share clients across all function apps as required.

Most SDKs have connection pooling and thread safe execution built in, so they are designed for cases where concurrency is a requirement.